# How to create drop down in Django using the list in view

Tags: python, django

How can I create a dropdown in my template using the list values present in my view. I do not want this to be present in my models.py. My views.py has generated some values which I would like to display in dropdown.

Example: Say I have z=[1,2,3,4]. I would like this value to be displayed in a drop down box in the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the view:

```
def your_handler(request):
    z = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    return render(request, 'yourapp/your_template.html', {'z': z})
```

in the template:

```
<label>values in z<label>
<select id="the-id">
    {% for i in z %}
    <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: glat it helped.

Comment: @alfonso.kim . hey can tell how to get the selected value of the dropdown in view function in above question. for eg. if I choose 3 then how can I get this value in a function on view.py page without using any Django models and forms

Comment: @girijesh96 check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) about request and response objects