# [Django]How to return value to view after select item from dropdown list

Tags: python, django

Though I read django document but I am still confused how to use request.POST to get value from dropdown list to make query to databse.. And how to return the details of selected value back to frontend in order to show the result?

Suppose I can select "region" in dropdown box and it would return the detail of that restaurant under that region category

#### Class Restaurant

```py
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restId = models.AutoField(db_column='restId', primary_key=True)
    restName = models.TextField(db_column='restName')
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.TextField()
    ratings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    cuisine = models.TextField()
    region = models.TextField()
    last_modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "restaurant"
```

#### views.py

```py
# def index_view(request):
    # rest_list = Restaurant.objects.all()
    # context = {
    #     'rest_list': rest_list
    # }
    # return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def get_name(request):
    # region = Restaurant.objects.all().order_by('region').values_list('region', flat=True)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        rest_form = RestaurantForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'rest_form': rest_form})
```

#### index.html

```html
        {% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <select name = "rest_value">
                {% for rest in rest_form %}
                    <option value = {{ rest }} ></option>
                {%  endfor %}
            </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Select" name="region">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

#### forms.py

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Restaurant

class RestaurantForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ['region']
```

Comment: checkout how forms are used in django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/

Comment: try with this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45198527/how-to-create-drop-down-in-django-using-the-list-in-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide an answer in the context of your question, you can make it work with the following code (*note:* untested); but please see the notes at the bottom:

*Python View:*

```
def index_view(request):
    selected_region = None
    restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        # Filter restaurants by selected region, but only on a POST
        selected_region = request.POST.get("region")
        restaurants = restaurants.filter(region=selected_region)

    # Get a list of all unique regions (group by region)  
    regions = Restaurant.objects.order_by('region').values_list('region', flat=True)

    context = {
        'regions': regions,
        'restaurants': restaurants,
        'selected_region': selected_region
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

*Django Template:*

```
<h1>Index</h1>
<form method="post">
    <select name="region">
         {% for region in regions %}
             <option
              value="{{ region }}"
              {% if selected_region == region %}
                  selected="selected"
              {% endif %}
             >{{ region }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
{% if selected_region %}
  <p>
    Nice, you selected: {{ selected_region }}!
  </p>
  <p>
    Restaurants in this region:
  </p>
  <ul>
     {% for restaurant in restaurants %}
       <li>{{ restaurant.restName }}</li>
     {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

**Some points:**

- You named `action` on the form as "selectRegion" in your code. That posts it to a different URL. In my example I've removed `action` from the form so that it posts it back to the same URL as `index.html`.
- If you've got a lot of "regions", you'll probably a want to store them in a different table and make `region` a foreign key in `Restuarant`.
- As others have pointed out, you should seriously consider using [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) instead. The main reason for this is that Django, when using the builtin forms functionality, already takes care of most of the heavy lifting for: sanitisation, validation and rendering.

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried to use ModelField as I built a database for the models. But it fails to render 'region' field to the dropdown list. Please check my updated code.

Comment: When you're rendering your form, you only need something like this:

`<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
 </form>`

The reason being that the `form` instance handles rendering of the form for you. Now, this is ignoring *many* interesting things that you can do, including customisation of the actual look/feel of the form.