# retrive data according to the dropdown list item selected, in django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views

I have a dropdown list that is populated with "price range" from the database.
I want to show the relevant "price" according to the "Price Range"
for example, in the database, I have this row

```
Price Range                  Price
"0-1500"                      28
"1501-1750"                   30
```

What I want when I select the range "1501-1750" the corresponding "price" value shown in an input field or paragraph tag.

Below are my Model.py, views.py, and home.html files

```
models.py

from django.db import models
        
class price_range(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

---

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from range.models import price_range

def showobj(request):
  displayvalues = price_range.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'range/home.html', {"range":displayvalues})
```

---

```
home.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Range</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>

    <select name="drop1">
        <option selected disabled="true">Select the Price Range</option>
        {% for results in range %}
        <option> {{results.name}}   </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question Helped me a lot in creating the logic for this problem.
[[Django]How to return value to view after select item from dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826337/djangohow-to-return-value-to-view-after-select-item-from-dropdown-list)

```
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
from range.models import price_range

def showobj(request):
    selected_range = None
    range_price = price_range.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
       
        selected_range = request.POST.get("range")
        range_price = range_price.filter(name=selected_range)

    
    price = price_range.objects.order_by('name').values_list('name', flat=True)

    context = {
        'ranges': price,
        'range_price': range_price,
        'selected_range': selected_range,
    }

    return render(request, 'range/price_range.html', context)
```

---

```
price_range.html

<center>
<h1>Index</h1>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
 {% if selected_range %}
       {% for rest in range_price %}
      <input name="price_value" value="{{ rest.price }}"></input>
     {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
    <select name="range">
         <option selected disabled="true">Select the Price Range</option>
         {% for range in ranges %}
             <option value="{{ range }}" {% if selected_range == range %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>{{ range }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">

</form>
</center>
```